# What does this limitation mean?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, notation

In a book I'm reading, the following statement is written:

> Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$ be parameters with $\varepsilon<\delta$, $\{x_{\varepsilon}\}_{\varepsilon>0}\subset(0,1)$ be a sequence such that $x_{\varepsilon}\to a\in(0,1)$ and $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. The following holds:
>   $$
> \lim_{\delta\to0}f(x_{\varepsilon}+\delta)=f(a).
> $$
>   (I rewrite a littele bit.)

**What does this limitation mean?** I think that
$$
\lim_{\delta\to0}f(x_{\varepsilon}+\delta)=\lim_{\delta\to0}\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}f(x_{\varepsilon}+\delta)(=f(a))
$$
but is this correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the point is that $\epsilon$ depends on $\delta$, so you may as well have written $\epsilon = \epsilon(\delta)$.

Notice that you write that $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$ are parameters with $\epsilon<\delta$. Thus, as $\delta\to 0$, you will also have that $\epsilon\to 0$. This is why you don't need to mention $\epsilon$ explicitly in the limit: $\epsilon$ will automatically go to $0$ as $\delta$ does so.

It might become clearer, if you write
$$\lim_{\delta\to0}f(x_{\varepsilon}+\delta)=\lim_{\delta\to 0}f(x_{\epsilon(\delta)}+\delta).$$

Comment: Thank you for giving answer. Although I'm sorry for unclear question, it seems that $\varepsilon>0$ is first given and then, for $\varepsilon>0$, $\delta>0$ is artificially taken. So, $\varepsilon>0$ maybe does not depend on $\delta>0$, I think. If I misunderstand, please tell me that.

Comment: But the $\epsilon$ you are looking at must be smaller than $\delta$. So as $\delta$ goes to $0$, you cannot still have a fixed $\epsilon$.